# Python: Bizarre issue with imported function within While Loop

Tags: python, audio

So I have a bit of a conundrum. Let's start with the relevant fragment of my code.

```
from RECORD import recordSystem

recTime = 30 #Amount of time(seconds) I want to record the audio input

while True: #I want to keep this active while system is running

#Standard raspberry Pi input sensors. 
if(GPIO.input(LedPin4) == GPIO.LOW and GPIO.input(LedPin5) == GPIO.HIGH:  
  recordSystem(recTime) #when condition is met run the code.
```

So the function I am trying to run comes from another script I wrote. And it works. It records analog audio and creates a .wav file in my project folder. The problem with this code is that it was working perfectly find yesterday and now is not. Nothing has been changed or touched. It just does not want to work. What happens is that the loop starts, and when the condition is met the function is launched properly and I get my "recording" notice in the compiler. Yet it NEVER stops recording. 
When I just do the following outside of the loop:

```
recordSystem(recTime)
```

The function runs through properly without any problems. So it has to do something with calling the function inside the loop. Yet, it was working without any problems for a while. 
Could anyone give me a best guest on what might be going on? 
Much appreciated!

Comment: Is that the exact formatting of your code?

Comment: That code won't run. It has a syntax error due to that extra `(`, and it's not properly indented. But apart from that, why are you calling `recordSystem` inside an infinite `while` loop?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I wrote this code looking at my actual one without just doing a copy and paste. The extra ( is not present in the actual script. I have an infinite while loop because this system needs to continuously run while the application is active. Now, this is just a snipped of the code I do have other statements that follow this but they are no relevant to this particular problem I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `break` statement after your `recordSystem(recTime)` should do the trick! I also fixed the indentation, and removed an extra `(` from the code:

```
from RECORD import recordSystem

recTime = 30 #Amount of time(seconds) I want to record the audio input

while True: #I want to keep this active while system is running

    #Standard raspberry Pi input sensors. 
    if GPIO.input(LedPin4) == GPIO.LOW and GPIO.input(LedPin5) == GPIO.HIGH:  
        recordSystem(recTime) #when condition is met run the code. 
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. So aside from needing to stay within the loop to fulfill more tasks, I did try your solution just to see if maybe the while loop was making it mess up. And sadly no, the break won't make the function play through. It still getting stock on recording.

Comment: Can you add you `recordSystem` function to the question?